# Triggering the push button on the analog input of the L293D motorshield

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I'm trying to drive a **12v dc motor** using three push buttons, one to turn clockwise, the other counter-clockwise and the other to stop the motor completely.

However the code below is not working, apparently it feels like I'm doing something wrong in the code on the connect buttons on the analog part of the engine shield L293D.

The Arduino is powered by a **9v** battery and **motor shield **L293D** with an external power.

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

    AF_DCMotor motor(1);

    int val; 

    #define btnleft A0 
    #define btncenter A1 
    #define btnright A2 


    void setup() 
    { 
      pinMode(btnleft, INPUT);      
      analogWrite(btnleft, HIGH);  
      pinMode(btncenter, INPUT);
      analogWrite(btncenter, HIGH);
      pinMode(btnright, INPUT);
      analogWrite(btnright, HIGH);
    } 

    void loop() 
    { 
     val=digitalRead(btnleft);  
       if(val!=1) 
        {
        Serial.print("LEFT: ");
        motor.setSpeed(255); 
        motor.run(FORWARD); 
        delay(3800); 
        }

     val=digitalRead(btncenter);
       if(val!=1)
        {
        Serial.print("CENTER"); 
        motor.setSpeed(255); 
        motor.run(BACKWARD);
        delay(3800); 
        }

     val=digitalRead(btnright);
       if(val!=1)
        {
        Serial.print("RIGHT"); 
        motor.run(RELEASE);
        delay(3000);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `analogWrite()` on an input?

Comment: I thought it was to be an analog input in motorshield

Comment: So then why would you treat it as an output regardless?

Comment: Maybe he means `digitalWrite`, to set the internal pull-ups. Doing an analogWrite of 1 doesn't make a heap of sense.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As noted in Nick Gammon's comment, `digitalWrite(btnleft, INPUT)` (etc.) would make a lot more sense than does `analogWrite(btnleft, INPUT)` (etc.).</strike>

---

*Edit:* `INPUT` is a constant defined in `wiring.h` (as in following extract), and is intended for use in [`pinMode()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PinMode) calls that set an IO pin's mode to one of `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, or `INPUT_PULLUP`.  It's inept to use it in a call of either [`digitalWrite()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalWrite) or `analogWrite()`.

```
    #define HIGH 0x1
    #define LOW  0x0    
    #define INPUT 0x0
    #define OUTPUT 0x1
    #define INPUT_PULLUP 0x2
```

---

Note that [`digitalWrite`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalWrite) to an input-mode pin leaves the pin in input-mode, while an [`analogWrite`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite) to an input-mode pin changes the pin to output-mode.

When you want a pin to be input-mode with pullup, it is simpler to use `INPUT_PULLUP` as the mode parameter, rather than using two separate calls.  That is, instead of saying [`pinMode(pin, INPUT);`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/pinMode) followed by `digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);`, just say

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Comment: Actually `digitalWrite(btnleft, INPUT)` is not correct. You should only call `digitalWrite` with a `HIGH` or `LOW` parameter, to avoid misunderstandings. Ok, for arduino `INPUT = LOW = 0x0` and `OUTPUT = HIGH = 0x1`, but... I don't think that someone writing `digitalWrite(btnleft, INPUT)` wants the pin set at 0